# Unable to install HTML5 drag and drop multi-file upload plugin in Grails 3.1.1

Tags: grails, file-upload, grails-plugin, grails-3.1

Has anybody has and success installing the [HTML5 drag and drop multi-file upload plugin](https://github.com/dustindclark/grails-uploadr/blob/master/README.md) in a Grails 3 application.

I have mapped

> compile "org.grails.plugins:uploadr:1.2.11"

in the build.grade file but then also getting this

```
| Error Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':testRuntime'. Type 'gradle dependencies' for more information
```

Can anybody help me to get me out.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the Grails 3 version. See documentation here: http://grails.org/plugins.html#plugin/grails3-uploadr and try

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.nayidisha.grails.uploadr:grails3-uploadr:3.0'
}
```

instead of the Grails 2.x dependency you have above.

Comment: Great @sbglasius. Thanks a lot. This is working for grails 3.x version

Answer (score 0):

It's only for grails 2 :/ see the issue : https://github.com/dustindclark/grails-uploadr/issues/2

Comment: nothing has given there in that link.
You can check once.There is no description about the issues.
And see the below link. And I think it is for grails 3.1 version
But I don't why it is not working.

https://github.com/dustindclark/grails-uploadr/tree/3.1-upgrade

Comment: Ok I don't know :/ since it's in the "issues" I interpreted that it's something TODO